# Organization Chart Using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, organizational-chart

Hi I'm thinking whether it is possible to generate an organization chart as shown in the below image using HTML & CSS

[image]

I have created an organization chart like in this http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/4tgCu/5.

```
    <div class="tree">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">President Director <br/>Tetsuo Nakai</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            HR &amp; Administration<br/>
                            Heli Neo<br/>Manager</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">IT Administrator <br/>Ericson Ginting<br/>Assistant Manager</a>

                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">IT Engineer <br/>I Wayan Purushottama<br/>Engineer</a>

                                        <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">IT Support<br/>Juanda F Butar Butar<br/>Assistant Engineer</a>
                                        </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="just-line"><br/><br/><br/></a>
                                    <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">IT Support<br/>David Alwis<br/>Assistant Engineer</a>

                                        <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">IT Support<br/>Nico Simanjuntak<br/>Technician</a>
                                        </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



        /*Now the CSS*/
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

    .tree
    {
        width: auto;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .tree ul {
        padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .tree li {
        float: left; text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    /*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

    .tree li::before, .tree li::after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 50%; height: 20px;
    }
    .tree li:after{
        right: auto; left: 50%;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    /*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
    any siblings*/
    .tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
        display: none;
    }

    /*Remove space from the top of single children*/
    .tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

    /*Remove left connector from first child and 
    right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

li a.just-line {
    display: none;
}
a.just-line + ul {
    padding-top: 74px;
}
a.just-line + ul:before {
    height: 74px;
}
```

But its spreading horizontally and breaking up the chart and spreading to multiple pages

My organization is asking that the whole chart should fit into a single page and it should occupy the whole page.

Kindly need help in generating the chart as shown in figure using HTML & CSS as i'm getting data dynamically.